# How to install Ubuntu on a Non-Ubuntu Linux without USB/CD?

Tags: system-installation

I have a mini laptop "Acer Aspire One" which has not been used for a very long time and it has an older distribution of Linux (Linpus Linux Lite v1.0). I don't have a spare USB stick right now, so how do I install Ubuntu without one, or should I buy a USB stick instead?

Here is an image of the mini laptop:
[image]

Comment: The commands you have given me don't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need UNetBootin: This is a program used to make Live USBs, but it has an option to install the live system directly in your hard drive.

Install Unetbootin:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

and download the Ubuntu ISO. Run the program, select the ISO and then select your hard drive. When you reboot, it will ask if you want to boot the normal OS or the Live Ubuntu. Select the second option. You will be able to install Ubuntu from there.

Comment: Your laptop's RAM memory is very low, so I would recommend Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu